# Evenly Distribute items in a bucket( or having a property ) to another bucket(or array) following property

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm

Evenly Distribute items in a bucket( or having a property ) to another bucket(or array) following property ...

I have an array like

```
 Array
(
    [type1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1,
            [1] => 2,
            [2] => 3,
            [3] => 4
        )

    [type2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5,
            [1] => 6,
            [2] => 7,
            [3] => 8
        )

    [type3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9,
            [1] => 10,
            [2] => 11,
            [3] => 12
        )
    [type4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 13,
            [1] => 14,
            [2] => 15,
            [3] => 16
        )
)
```

SO i need to sort it into an array such that each element of this new array will have all the types of elements equally distributed to each of the elements of new array

What i Need

```
    array(
[0]=>array(1,5,9,13)
[1]=>array(2,6,10,14)
[2]=>array(3,7,11,15)
[3]=>array(4,8,12,16)
)
```

The issue here is the first array's sub-arrays may have varying no of elements

A simpler version: Imagine u have a set of horses from different countries
How do you organize a "n" ( here 4 ) number of different races so that in all the races the country of the horse present is as evenly distributed as possible

In Db its something like

```
regid nation    race1
1     country1  1
2     country2  1
3     country3  0
4     country1  1
5     country1  1
```

where regid is id no for each participant and race1 is to denote if its participating in that race or not

Comment: . . This is tagged "mysql".  Do you really want a MySQL solution or a php solution?  If you want a MySQL solution, what does the data look like in the database?

Comment: Added a sample db data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following generates two arrays: `$values` contains the values, and `$out` contains keys in the form `type1:3`. The variable `$max` determines the maximum number of sets:

```
$arr['type1'] = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$arr['type2'] = array(6, 7, 8, 9);
$arr['type3'] = array(10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15);
$arr['type4'] = array(16, 17, 18, 19);
$arr['type5'] = array(20, 21, 22, 23, 24);
$max = 5;
$out = array();
$values = array();
$i = 0;
foreach ($arr as $key1 => $type){
    foreach ($type as $key2 => $item){
        $out[$i%$max][] = $key1.':'.$key2;
        $values[$i%$max][] = $item;
        $i++;
    }
}
var_dump($values);

[0] => array(1, 6, 11, 16, 21)
[1] => array(2, 7, 12, 17, 22)
[2] => array(3, 8, 13, 18, 23)
[3] => array(4, 9, 14, 19, 24)
[4] => array(5, 10, 15, 20)
```

Or you can access the array keys:

```
var_dump($out);

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => type1:0
            [1] => type2:0
            [2] => type3:1
            [3] => type4:0
            [4] => type5:1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => type1:1
            [1] => type2:1
            [2] => type3:2
            [3] => type4:1
            [4] => type5:2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => type1:2
            [1] => type2:2
            [2] => type3:3
            [3] => type4:2
            [4] => type5:3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => type1:3
            [1] => type2:3
            [2] => type3:4
            [3] => type4:3
            [4] => type5:4
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => type1:4
            [1] => type3:0
            [2] => type3:5
            [3] => type5:0
        )

)
```